# мой бот не хочет считывать файл асистента и выдает такую ошибку: Ошибка: содержимое файла пусто

Tags: python, telebot, python-openai

Ошибка: содержимое файла пусто
Ошибка при чтении файла: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код

```
import openai
import telebot
import logging

# Создаем экземпляр бота Telegram
bot = telebot.TeleBot("ключ")

# Настраиваем логирование ошибок
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

# Устанавливаем ваш API ключ OpenAI
openai.api_key = "ключ"

# Читаем содержимое файла
def read_file(file_id):
    try:
        # Получаем содержимое файла
        file_info = openai.File.retrieve(file_id)
    
        # Проверяем, что файл найден и не пустой
        if file_info and file_info.object == 'file':
            file_content = file_info.bytes.decode("utf-8")
            return file_content
        else:
            return "Ошибка: Файл не найден или пустой."
    except Exception as e:
        # Если возникает ошибка, выводим сообщение об ошибке
        print(f"Ошибка при чтении файла: {str(e)}")
        return None


# Обработчик входящих сообщений
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    try:
        # Читаем содержимое файла из ассистента
        file_content = read_file("file-76t0RvqaNKq6H72L15H9Hmkd")
    
        # Проверяем, что содержимое файла не пусто
        if file_content:
            # Отправляем содержимое файла пользователю
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=file_content)
        else:
            # Если содержимое файла пусто, отправляем сообщение об ошибке
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="Ошибка: содержимое файла пусто.")
    except Exception as e:
        # В случае ошибки отправляем сообщение об ошибке
        bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=f"Ошибка: {str(e)}")

# Запускаем бота Telegram
bot.polling()
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности: не надо в заголовок вопроса впихивать весь текст вопроса.

Comment: Очень смущает название файла, похож на динамически сгенерированный tmp. Файл с подобным названием действительно существует и не пуст?

Comment: Да это айди файла в ассистенте и там есть текст, я пробовал и текстовый фай и ворд файл, он все равно не считывает

Comment: Приведите **полный стек-трейс ошибки прямо в вопросе**. Той ошибки, которую вы процитировали в заголовке, нет в коде вашей программы. Поэтому вообще непонятно, что происходит и как это трактовать.

Comment: в терминале выдает такую ошибку: Ошибка при чтении файла: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Извините, мне ещё раз написать, что вы должны сделать, или вы всё-таки прочитаете и сделаете? Правила придуманы не просто так. По пересказу ошибки можно долго гадать. Только **полный стек-трейс** и только **прямо в вопросе**, а не в комментариях. При этом ещё непонятно, "Ошибка: содержимое файла пусто", про которую вы написали в заголовке вопроса, выводится одновременно с ошибкой `decode` или как, или где?

Comment: да одновременно

Comment: Тогда приложите скриншот происходящего к вашему вопросу. И скопируйте всё-таки полный трейс ошибки, тоже в вопрос.

Comment: прислал скриншот

Comment: А, понятно, вторую ошибку сам бот уже говорит, я не заметил надпись в боте. А где вы такой пример подсмотрели? Я не могу пока найти нормальную документацию, но может нужно брать не `file_info.bytes`, а `file_info.body`? Похоже, в `bytes` у вас количество байт лежит, а не сам контент.

Comment: попробовал. выдает: Ошибка при чтении файла: body. С примером мне помог сам Чат ГПТ, потому что примеры из документации тоже нерабочие

Comment: Ну в общем вам нужно посмотреть как-то, что за объект `file_info` и какие у него есть методы. Попробуйте сделать `print(file_info)`, `print(type(file_info))` и `print(dir(file_info))`. Последний принт покажет все поля и методы, которые есть у этого объекта.